# Tool for associative graphing

Tags: charts, mind-mapping

I'm looking for an app or some computational way that would help me create interactive associated lists. Basically, I have three columns of data that have many to many relationships, and when one is selected I'd like to show it's associations. Here's an example:

[image: Association Map]

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Excel could do this, but it would take a bit of spreadsheet gymnastics.

Answer (score 0):

A mind mapping tool that supports scripts might be what you are looking for.  There are many such [tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=mind%20map&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS513US513&oq=mind%20map&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60j69i61.3576j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) out there, however it seems like you need one with a scripting engine.  They do [exist](https://www.google.com/search?q=mind%20mapping%20tool%20with%20scripting&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS513US513&oq=mind%20mapping%20tool%20with%20scripting&aqs=chrome..69i57.6977j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), however I have never used one with scripts before.  It cant hurt to check them out.